# How to use use Cookiecontainer cookies in CefSharp Browser to open the page with same session

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I am having issues while i want to use the Cookiecontainer cookies of httpwebrequest in CeFsharp browser to open the page with same session.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?